# How to fit data points to a curve of the form y = c.A^n.exp(x)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have set of data points shown by the solid markers, as shown in figure and I would like to fit a curve of the form:

[image] 
[image]

That means for each of the lines I need equations of the form:

[image]

Known values are y1, y2, y3 and x, unknown parameters are c, A1, A2, A3, n. How can this be done in Python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fitting an exponent in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675145/fitting-an-exponent-in-python)

Comment: Kindly specify input and output. Which values are given (e.g. x,y,n)? Which are your fitting parameters (e.g c, A)?

Comment: @BerndGit Known values are y1, y2, y3 and x, unknown parameters are c, A1, A2, A3, n.

Comment: This question looks strange: Based on you last statement you could calculate:  ´c*A1^n = y1 / exp(x)´, or if you select on c and n:  ´A1 = log( y1 / (c*exp(x)) ) / log (n)´

Answer (score 0):

Your system is overdetermined as written.
For each `i = 1, 2, 3`, fitting `y_i / exp(x)` independently gives an estimate for the coefficient `c A_i^n`.

There is probably some additional relation between your variables.