# exponential decay regression model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, non-linear-regression

I have just started learning the sklearn module and have been importing data and finding the linear regression model and using it to predict more values.

I am now trying to find the relationship between the displacement of an engine and the mpg.  but when I graphed it, it looks more like an exponential decay; how would I find the regression model for this graph [Graph of engine displacement and mpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5VfY.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fitting exponential decay with no initial guessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938042/fitting-exponential-decay-with-no-initial-guessing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def exp_decay(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-x*b) + c

X = (your data)
Y = (your data)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_decay, X, Y, p0=(1,1,1))
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)