# Calculate Decay Rate in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, statistics

I have dataset which somewhat follows an exponentional decay

```
df_A
Period  Count
0       1600
1       894
2       959
3       773
4       509
5       206
```

I want to calculate the decay rate by using 2 methods as I'm expecting both to give the same result, however, I get different results?

This is the first method:

```
decay_rate1 = (10**(log(df_A['Count'].iloc[5]/df_A['Count'].iloc[0]) / 5)) - 1
```

This is the second method:

```
decay_rate2 = np.log(df_A['Count'].iloc[0])/log(df_A['Count'].iloc[5]
```

What is the correct method of calculating the decay rate of a dataset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fitting exponential decay with no initial guessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938042/fitting-exponential-decay-with-no-initial-guessing)

Comment: I saw that post, but I think that question/answer has rather been made over-complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "over-complicated". Can you explain your 2 methods? I'm not sure I follow how you arrived by them? In any case, `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` does all the heavy lifting for you:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def f(t, a, b):
    return a * np.exp(-b * t)


(a, b), *_ = curve_fit(f, df.Period, df.Count)
```

Result:

```py
In [4]: a
Out[4]: 1519.9510695102867

In [5]: b
Out[5]: 0.29266498021489273
```

[image: curve fit]

Note that due to your data having quite large values, you'll actually get a `RunTimeWarning`, so you can scale your `df.Count` column and still get the decay rate, `b`:

```py
(a, b), *_ = curve_fit(f, df.Period, df.Count / df.Count.max())
```

Output:

```py
In [6]: a
Out[6]: 0.9499694152031338

In [7]: b
Out[7]: 0.29266497643362804
```

You can also recover the true `a` by multiplying by `df.Count.max()`:

```py
In [8]: a * df.Count.max()
Out[8]: 1519.9510643250142
```